# switching from sandbox to paypal live

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I am getting the following error when switching from sandbox to live paypal.please help me how to solve this error.

```
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2015-06-10T01:59:03Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 4ce24a1abd742
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 85.0
    [BUILD] => 16770825
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10501
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Invalid Configuration
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => This transaction cannot be processed due to an invalid merchant configuration.
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
    [AMT] => 555.00
    [CURRENCYCODE] => USD
)
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Checkout extends CI_Controller {


public function direct_payment() {

$item = $this->session->userdata['item_data']['item'];

$price = $this->session->userdata['item_data']['price'];

$quantity = $this->session->userdata['item_data']['quantity'];

$card_type = $this->input->post('card_type');

$card_fname = $this->input->post('card_fname');

$card_lname = $this->input->post('card_lname');

$creditcard_number = $this->input->post('creditcard_number');

$crd_month=$this->input->post('crd_month');

$crd_year=$this->input->post('crd_year');

$security_code=$this->input->post('security_code'); 

//$order_id  = $this->payment_model->save_order();

$respounse  = $this->payment_model->do_direct_payment($card_type,$card_fname,$card_lname,$creditcard_number,$crd_month,$crd_year,$security_code); 

echo '<pre>';

print_r($respounse);

exit;

if($respounse['ACK'] == 'SuccessWithWarning' or $respounse['ACK']== 'Success' or $respounse['ACK']== 'Pending') {

    //$this->db->update('orders', array('order_status'=>'New', 'transaction_id'=>$respounse['TRANSACTIONID'], 'payment_type' =>'Credit Card', 

    //'payment_status' =>$respounse['ACK'],'payment_recevied'=>$respounse['AMT'], 'payment_symbol'=>$respounse['CURRENCYCODE']), array('id'=> $order_id));

    //$this->cart->destroy();

    //$this->session->set_userdata(array(

    //'last_id'=> $order_id,'transaction'=>$respounse['TRANSACTIONID']));

    $this->session->set_flashdata("succes","Your Order is succesfully placed.");

    redirect("contents/credit");

    } else {

    //$this->db->update('orders', array('order_status'=>'Failed', 'payment_type' =>'Credit Card', 

    //'payment_status' =>$respounse['ACK']), array('id'=> $order_id));

    $this->session->set_flashdata("error","Error occur in your payment transacion.");

    redirect("contents/credit");        

    }   

    }

}
```

**Model:**

```
class payment_model extends CI_Model {

function do_direct_payment($card_type,$card_fname,$card_lname,$creditcard_number,$crd_month,$crd_year,$security_code) {

    $sandbox = TRUE;
    // Set PayPal API version and credentials.

    $api_version = '85.0';

    $api_endpoint = ($sandbox == 0 )? 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp' : 'https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp';

    $api_username = ($sandbox == 0) ? '------' : '-------';

    $api_password = ($sandbox == 0) ? '-------' : '------';

    $api_signature =  ($sandbox == 0) ? '--------' : '-------';

    $request_params = array (
        'METHOD' => 'DoDirectPayment', 
        'USER' => $api_username, 
        'PWD' => $api_password, 
        'SIGNATURE' => $api_signature, 
        'VERSION' => $api_version, 
        'PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale',                  
        'IPADDRESS' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
        'CREDITCARDTYPE' => $card_type, 
        'ACCT' => $creditcard_number,                       
        'EXPDATE' => $crd_month.$crd_year,          
        'CVV2' => $security_code, 
        'FIRSTNAME' => 'ibad', 
        'LASTNAME' => 'anjum', 
        'STREET' => '11 gg', 
        'CITY' => 'peshawar', 
        'STATE' => 'state',                     
        'COUNTRYCODE' => 'PK', 
        'ZIP' => '10200', 
        'EMAIL' => '-----',
        'AMT' => 555, 
        'CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD', 
        'DESC' => 'Testing Payments Pro' 
    );

    // Loop through $request_params array to generate the NVP string.

    $nvp_string = '';

    foreach($request_params as $var=>$val)
    {
        $nvp_string .= '&'.$var.'='.urlencode($val);    
    }

    // Send NVP string to PayPal and store response
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $api_endpoint);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvp_string);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    //print_r($result);

    return $result_array = $this->NVPToArray($result);
}

public function NVPToArray($NVPString) {
    $proArray = array();
    while(strlen($NVPString)) {
        // name
        $keypos= strpos($NVPString,'=');
        $keyval = substr($NVPString,0,$keypos);
        // value
        $valuepos = strpos($NVPString,'&') ? strpos($NVPString,'&'): strlen($NVPString);
        $valval = substr($NVPString,$keypos+1,$valuepos-$keypos-1);
        // decoding the respose
        $proArray[$keyval] = urldecode($valval);
        $NVPString = substr($NVPString,$valuepos+1,strlen($NVPString));
    }
    return $proArray;
}   

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the docs, the error code [10501](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/errorcodes/) occurs when the billing agreement is disabled or inactive.You should enable your PayPal Payment Pro in your account. 
You could try doing the following::

- Open your developer.paypal.com account.
- Open applications to access your account.
- Click the account you are trying to upgrade to Payment Pro.
- Click Profile to find the option Upgrade to Pro in the dialogue box.

Answer (score 0):

If it worked on your Sandbox, it seems to me an account issue.

For account issues I would recommend getting contact with PayPal (bottom of http://www.paypal.com), and they will get the right team to support you.

Even if later they find it's technical, they will ask merchant technical services to support. But again, I think this is account issue. They will guide you through the necessary process.